# AjaxfileUpload error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a simple ajaxtoolkit fileupload control and every time I click "Upload" all I get is an error. I tried placing breakpoint in the "AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" function but it won't even get fired.. (maybe because upload isn't complete yet?) what should I do to make it work?

here is the error:
[image]

**here is my aspx:**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

       <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
            onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" ThrobberID="myThrobber" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"/>

    </div>
    </form>
```

**and here is the funcion behind:**

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = "038191904";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + id + "/scanned_docs/"));
        string filePath = "~/Member_Data/" + id + "/images/";
        string path = filePath + e.FileName;
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath) + e.FileName);

        //db1.insert_pic_slide(id, path);

    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I added a picture, check the edit

Comment: If I remember correctly, this control writes the file to a temp folder before the UploadComplete event fires.  Make sure the account your IIS App Pool is running as has write permissions to the virtual directory the code is running.

Comment: thanks, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you can't get it to run locally, that's probably not the problem--if it runs locally but not on your server, it could be the cause.  I would suggest downloading the entire demo project from here http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.html

Comment: FYI, not an answer, but I've submitted the "red error of death" complaint to DevExpress over on GitHub and referenced your question: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/573

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was happening to me, and I did two things to fix it:

**1)**  Update your site's web.config file to contain entries for the following:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

**2)** If the page you're uploading from is inside a folder with it's own web.config with deny anonymous authorization rules, make sure you add an allow for the AjaxFileUploadHandler like so:

```
<location path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: When I add this to my web.config, I get the http error 500.23 "An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode."

Comment: Lopsided, you need to add <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> under <system.webserver>

Comment: Adding the line to system.webserver fixed it for me.  I'm not sure why that's not in the official documentation on the sample site.  Thanks though!

Comment: Great man. It worked. Wondering why the guys at MS can't take care of such small silly things

Answer (score 0):

Just going to add this troubleshooting advice for the AjaxFileUpload control. If you added all of the web.config statements as recommended on this page and still get an error on upload, swap out the AjaxFileUpload control with the Ajax AsyncFileUpload control. The code between the two are almost identical to use and it will only take a minute to swap them out.

The AjaxFileUpload captures errors and it is very hard to find the real reason of the upload problem. The AsyncFileUpload will throw the actual error.

I spent a whole afternoon digging through forums on the AjaxFileUpload for what looked like a directory permissions/temp folder issue. I actually had a database error that I was able to fix 15 minutes after I swapped to the AsyncFileUpload and ran into the real problem.

The error that the AjaxFileUpload was throwing when I debugged in FireFox was:

ajaxfileupload error raising upload complete event and start new upload

And the IIS error was error 500.

Keep in mind it was just a database error. I added a column locally that I forgot to add to the hosting database, so it worked locally for me, but threw an error on the hosting server when I deployed.

Close to a whole day of work on something that should have taken 15 minutes to fix.