# Error in ajax file upload control of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am getting following error when i try to upload the file on the asp.net directly

```
index-1.jpg (image/jpeg) - 7.72 kb (error) (In red sign)

<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="imageUploader" CssClass="uploadBox" OnUploadComplete="imageuploader_onUploadComplete" ThrobberID="imagethrobber" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,bmp" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" runat="server" />
```

Following is my code.

```
            //=========== Uploaded file format ============================
            string filename = e.FileName;

            //============== Upload the file ==============================
            imageUploader.SaveAs("~/articleimage/"+filename);
```

Kindly please help me in solving this issue. I am using visual studio 2010 , .net 4 and ajaxcontroltoolkit for 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue an hour back. Found solution. Please see the below link.

[AjaxfileUpload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051845/ajaxfileupload-error)