# Ajax FileUpload Route/Querystring - DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, .net-4.5

I have a WebApp with an upload section.

To upload the files to a sql database I'm using a Ajax Toolkit Fileupload control.

I always get a similar error as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051845/ajaxfileupload-error), but after hours of testing, I figured out what is causing my Problem.

My upload control is located on the SidDetails.aspx page and if open the page directly
with 

**foo.com/Pages/SID/SidDetails.aspx** 

I'm able to upload files.

[image: Page Route]

but if I access the page via the route 

**foo.com/SID/My/1** 

I get a 500 internal server error

So I checked the link of the page that is causing the exception

**foo.com/SID/My/1/?contextKey={DA8BEDC8-B952-4d5d-8CC2-59FE922E2923}&done=1&guid=BD327457-2013-1E97-6ADE-28612D63758E**

For me, it looks like that is the problem, but I don't know how to fix this.

I already tried adding a route with query value

[image: Route with Query]

But i don't know if this is how you would approach it.



**Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP_AjaxFileUpload\E0E386A6-F5B5-1012-F6E5-1872E4D6EF69'.**

Thats the exception that is thrown by the upload control.

I would like to keep the routes but how can I fix the problem?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .net 4.5 and AjaxControlToolkit 7.0930

Kind regards

CarnVanBeck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into this too, and after going crazy I fixed it.

1. Download the [ajaxtoolkit source code project](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.Control.pre.js) and open it.
2. Change the following row:

   ```
   this._uploadUrl = 'AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd';
   ```

   to:

   ```
   this._uploadUrl = '/AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd';
   ```
3. Rebuild the project, get the new `.dll` and copy it to your `/bin` directory.

This will fix the issue, giving the right path to the handler.

PS: I came to this as:

- I noticed some strange duplicated calls to the handler, happening only in routed paths 
  (like `www.site.com/projects/edit/mypage`), where uploads failed.
- I noticed that in a test page, placed in the home dir of my site, the uploader was working fine.

Then I came to [this](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.Control.pre.js) page and noticed the mentioned row.

Comment: The Answer posted above works for me as well. And, I have submitted this issue to the codeplex site: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27754

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in Integrated Mode pool, you have to add this lines in the web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" 
                 type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```