# AjaxfileFileUpload Error in Local IIS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I get the same error screenshot as [AjaxfileUpload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051845/ajaxfileupload-error)

[image]

I tried everything mentioned in that article, but i cannot seem to get it working, i have also give complete write permissions to C:\Windows\Temp_AjaxFileUpload

Here is my code

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AjaxFileUpload_Test.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnUploadCompleteAll="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll" OnUploadStart="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadStart" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authorization>
          <add accessType="Allow" users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

it works fine in IIS Express, but not via Local IIS, even the application pool is running under an admin user account. thoughts?

below is the IIS log, i noticed a 404 error for the post back although the HTTP handler is registered, does this matter?

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-06-14 07:25:01
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-06-14 07:25:01 ::1 DEBUG /AjaxFileUpload_Test/WebForm1.aspx - 80 - ::1 - 401 0 0 60
2016-06-14 07:25:03 ::1 GET /AjaxFileUpload_Test/WebForm1.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 354
2016-06-14 07:25:03 ::1 GET /AjaxFileUpload_Test/__browserLink/requestData/e2f4a8e002fe4f38afcb6f92aa282f6d version=2 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 33
2016-06-14 07:25:12 ::1 POST /AjaxFileUpload_Test/WebForm1.aspx contextKey=AjaxFileUpload1&start=1&queue=1& 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 3652
2016-06-14 07:25:12 ::1 POST /AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd contextKey=AjaxFileUpload1&fileId=5CBB390C-9248-7FD8-AD8E-7A07B3A20C61&fileName=uploadtest.zip&chunked=false&firstChunk=true 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2016-06-14 07:25:12 ::1 POST /AjaxFileUpload_Test/WebForm1.aspx contextKey=AjaxFileUpload1&done=1&guid=5CBB390C-9248-7FD8-AD8E-7A07B3A20C61& 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 33
```

permissions on the folder c:\temp_AjaxFileUpload
[image]

IIS Anonymous authentication
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem ! Looks like refer -> https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/43

let me just post it here for others reference.

*The AjaxFileUpload client code expects the application root to be located at http://localhost/, so it calls the http://localhost/AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd url.
You can tune up this behavior by performing the following steps:

1. Set UseAbsoluteHandlerPath="false".
2. Change the AjaxFileUploadHandler path to {your_appname_in_IIS}/AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd in Web.config.*